# Check my math - Number of one-to-one functions $f$ from $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ to $\{1, \ldots, 2n-1\}$ such that $f(x) \neq 2x - 1$ for all $x$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

> What is the number of one-to-one functions $f$ from the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ to the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, 2n − 1\}$ so that $f(x) \neq 2x − 1$ for all $x$?

I'm not sure if I did the question correctly, so please provide feedback.
The total number of one-to-one functions is $(2n-1)(2n-2) \ldots (n)$ or $\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!}$. 
The number of one-to-one functions such that $f(x) = 2x-1$ is $n$. 
Thus, the total number of one-to-one functions such that $f(x) \neq 2x-1$ is:
$$\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!} - n$$

Comment: You want to discard the number of one to one functions such that $f(x)=2x-1$ for some $x$. Those are way more than $n$, for instance just considering the number of one to one functions such that $f(1)=1$ this is $(2n-1)!/(n-1)!$

Comment: How would you go about finding the number of one-to-one functions such that f(x) = 2x-1?